# Populating a combobox in the XAML vs codebehind

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox

I've got a combobox where the list of items will NEVER change. I'm curious where the population of said combobox should happen: the xaml or the codebehind. Is there any substantial reason to choose one over the other?

Comment: If you're following an MVVM pattern, you should avoid using the code behind.

Comment: @EsotericScreenName Not true. MVVM is not about no-code-behind. It's about putting logic where logic belongs and data where data belongs and UI where UI belongs.

Comment: @HighCore I'm making a specific comment on the question, not a blanket statement about MVVM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd define an Enum and then populate it from that using a ViewModel. But, I'm quite partial to MVVM, you might prefer to do it directly in XAML.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it matters if it goes into the XAML or Code-Behind, as long as it resides in either. I recommend trying to put it into the XAML first, as it's usually cleaner. Sometimes that isn't possible, as in the case where you pull a static list from a database.

Doing otherwise can be considered a violation of MVVM. Consider a case where we have a ComboBox of Vehicles

```
<ComboBox>
    <ComboBoxItem>Car</ComboBoxItem>
    <ComboBoxItem>Truck</ComboBoxItem>
    <ComboBoxItem>Bike</ComboItem>
</ComboBox>
```

But this could easily be represented with other controls

```
<RadioButton GroupName="vehicle" Content="Car" />
<RadioButton GroupName="vehicle" Content="Truck" />
<RadioButton GroupName="vehicle" Content="Bike" />
```

Now if we had defined a collection in the ViewModel containing "Vehicles" and bound our ComboBox to it, the ViewModel now effectively knows something about the implementation of the View in regards to Vehicles. This is where the violation occurs. The ViewModel should only know about the state of the view, in this case being what vehicle is chosen. the method of how the vehicle gets chosen is up to the View itself.